# Javascript taint analysis using WALA

Tags: javascript, static-analysis, firefox-os, taint

I am developing a Firefox OS application analysis tool that classifies given application to malicious or non malicious based on code analysis. My initial work is to perform static taint analysis of JavaScript files. Is it possible to do it using WALA. If yes, then how?

Comment: By WALA you mean **JS_WALA**?

Comment: No. I asked about Watson Libraries for Analysis (WALA) for java and javascript analysis. JS_WALA is wala tools implemented in javascript

Comment: @meskobalazs I wonder, though JavaScript is one of the powerful languages ruling the web , I couldn't find any static taint analysis tool for JavaScript based web applications :(

Comment: Well, doing static analysis for a dynamic, interpreted language is hard. I found this whitepaper, it could be interesting: http://prolangs.cs.vt.edu/refs/docs/weiryder-issta13.pdf

Comment: I think I am working on something very similar in my thesis, please contact me at: brian@de.ibm.com

Answer (score 0):

WALA does not include a production-quality taint analysis for JavaScript.  There is some sample code here that could help you get started:

https://github.com/wala/Examples/tree/master/TaintExamples/source/tutorial/examples